# PHP failing at compressing image

Tags: php

I'm having a hard time get this working:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) and isset($_GET['add']))
    {
    
       $category_image=rand(0,99999)."_".$_FILES['category_image']['name'];
       *************************issue here **************
       //Main Image
       $tpath1='images/'.$category_image;          
       $pic1=compress_image($_FILES["category_image"]["tmp_name"], $tpath1, 80);
     
        //Thumb Image 
       $thumbpath='images/thumbs/'.$category_image;     
       $thumb_pic1=create_thumb_image($tpath1,$thumbpath,'200','200');   
      ***********************************************************
          
       $data = array( 
                'category_name'  =>  $_POST['category_name'],
               'category_image'  =>  $category_image
                );      

        $qry = Insert('tbl_category',$data);    

        $cat_id=mysqli_insert_id($mysqli);  

       if(!is_dir('categories/'.$cat_id))
       {
    
            mkdir('categories/'.$cat_id, 0777);

            mkdir('categories/'.$cat_id.'/thumbs', 0777);
       }            

        $_SESSION['msg']="10";
 
        header( "Location:manage_category.php");
        exit;   
    }
```

I'm using a ubuntu 14.04, apache24 web server and PHP 5.6.

I'm using this code below to add a category, but I'm receiving a page with a **content Html** content and **a 500 HTTP response code**.
I'm receiving no error but I believe that the error is from the compress_image method which is:

```
function compress_image($source_url, $destination_url, $quality) 
{
  
    $info = getimagesize($source_url);

        if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg')
              $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_url);

        elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif')
              $image = imagecreatefromgif($source_url);

      elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png')
              $image = imagecreatefrompng($source_url);

        imagejpeg($image, $destination_url, $quality);

    return $destination_url;
}
```

I'm really stuck at this can you help me out?

Comment: Have you checked the php error log file? You can find its location by checking the results of `phpinfo();`

Comment: @Terminus error_log no value no value in the phpinfo() page

Comment: The log file is empty or there is no log file? If it's empty, I don't know how to help you:( If there is no log file, you should set that up, if you can (may not be allowed due to your hosting provider, I dunno)

Comment: @Terminus i own the server i'm the root of an ubuntu 14.04 server

Comment: Well then, enable logging to a file. If the server is only accessible to you, try setting up remote debugging with xdebug. That tool lets you set breakpoints and see the values of variables. You can also see the flow execution of your script. And it's free!

Comment: @Terminus the issue is the scritp is working fine in my local server using wamp server

Answer (score 0):

Well After i gave the folder permissions to the tmp folder

```
chown -R root:www-data /var/tmp
```

i still got the issues i enabled the error log using a simple try catch and i got the error

*Call to undefined function imagecreatefromjpeg()*

wich i solved by installing and enabling the gd module , since i'm using php5.6 i had to install the module :

```
apt-get install php5.6-gd
```

and i had to enable it  :

```
extension=php_gd2.dll
```